# Sorting project

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I've been trying to do a project using quick sort and bottom-up merge sort but I am stuck on quick sort. I've been able to come up with some code but whenever I try to run my program I get the error "quickSort(int[],int,int) in sort cannot be applied to (int[])" Any tips?
Here's code...

```
import java.util.Random;
public class main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Random gen = new Random();
      int[] a = new int[20];

      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        a[i] = gen.nextInt(100);

      printArray(a);
      quickSort(a);
    }

     private static void printArray(int[] a){
      for (int i : a)
        System.out.print(i + " ");
      System.out.println("");
    }
      private static void quickSort(int a[], int left, int right){
      int i = left, j = right;
      int tmp;
      int pivot = a[(left + right) / 2];
      while (i <= j) {
            while (a[i] < pivot)
                  i++;
            while (a[j] > pivot)
                  j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                  tmp = a[i];
                  a[i] = a[j];
                  a[j] = tmp;
                  i++;
                  j--;
        }
    }
    if (left < j)
        quickSort(a, left, j);
    if (i < right)
            quickSort(a, i, right);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `quickSort` function takes three arguments, but you are calling it with only one.

Answer (score 0):

your first call to quicksort doesn't have the right syntax. The method takes 3 parameters.

```
 quickSort(a);
```

I think you want

```
 quickSort(a, 0, 19); //might be 20 I don't know if it's size or last element index
```